# Searching a graph larger than 4GB on a 32bit machine

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, 32-bit, large-data

I have a graph that is somewhat larger than 4GB, larger than I can address on a 32bit machine.

I want to write a program that counts the number of vertices connected (directly and indirectly) to a specific node in the graph.

How can I do it if I can't load the whole graph into memory/swap at once?

**edit:** It is a directed graph, and I actually want to count the number of vertices from which I can get (in the right direction) to a specific vertex.

Comment: What programming language and Operating system do you want to do this with?

Comment: @EricLeschinski PHP on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you store your graph. In many cases you don't have to load the whole graph. For example, if your graph is stored as an adjacency matrix, you just need to extract one column/row, and there are many ways to do this efficiently depending on how the matrix is stored (for example fixed-length cells or HDF files). If your graph is stored as a list of nodes with pointers to other nodes, you can sometimes extract just the data for that node.
Bottom line, it depends on how you store your graph, but it is doable under many representations. The key point is that the representation has to be saved to disk in such a way that it does not have to be loaded all at once.

Comment: I'm not working with a language that supports pointers, I'm using hash tables to represent adjacent nodes. Does that mean the only real solution is to use C/C++?

Comment: @futlib, you can do in in many languages. do you have one hash table per node?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how to store it to disk and load it again when needed in PHP, I guess I'll need to figure that out.

Comment: One option is to just write it into a text file and then load only what you need. Another option is to use serialize (php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) which lets you save variables without hassle to disk. The point is that the representation has to be saved to disk in such a way that it does not have to be loaded all at once, either in separate files or in a file that you can load only a part of it.